# how to instantiate an XmlPullParser in android-8?

Tags: android, xmlpullparser, android-2.2-froyo

I am trying to use an XMLPullParser to parse some XML for an android app.  I am classpathing in android.jar from the android-8 SDK.

Alas, this code:

```
import android.util.Xml;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;

class InstantiateXMLPullParser {
  public static void main( String args[] ){
    XmlPullParser xpp = Xml.newPullParser();
  }
}
```

fails with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
        at android.util.Xml.newPullParser(Xml.java:15)
        at InstantiateXMLPullParser.main(InstantiateXMLPullParser.java:6)
```

I suspect I need to specify an implementation somewhere -- it looks like once upon a time Android used org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatPullParser as its default pull parser, but that no longer seems to be the case.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to have more fundamental problems. `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!` will only come when you attempt to use `android.jar` outside of Android. Try building an Android application and running it on a device or emulator, and you will get your pull parser.

Comment: yes, the problems are more fundamental.  was trying to do some stubbing out of my own, outside of the heavy, slow emulator.  thanks very much for your quick answer.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. Your answer helped me debug an issue that I had been trying to troubleshoot all weekend! : )

Answer (score 0):

From the [API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
```